# The type or namespace name 'FileIO' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using  Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO; in my C# code  in VISUAL STUDIO CODE.
But I am getting the error 'FileIO' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualBasic'

Can anyone please help on how to add the reference for FileIO

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS2ri.png)

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your code in text form, not as image

Comment: if you develop app in C# use `System.IO` instead `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO`. i can't even imagine why you use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO`...

Comment: Well, that namespace [seems to exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio?view=netframework-4.7.2). have you checked the references?. @MaciejS. probably some code porting or developer used to old time vb6

Comment: You are using .NETCore, not the .NETFramework.  Support for FileIO is planned for .NETCore version 3.0, currently in preview.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are missing the reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic in your project. You will need to add the reference to your project.

Reviewing your screenshot it appears you are using Visual Studio Code. If this is a .NET Core application FileIO is not in the .NET Core library. Assuming you are trying to parse a file you will want to utilize System.IO.FileSystem instead https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem/